# global_messages not working

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem with Magento global_messages that don't show up. No notice/error/confirmation message is showing.

I have in my theme files

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

I've also tried the following:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true));
echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
```

In my theme page.xml i have added:

`<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
<block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>`

On other stores from the same installation messages works(different theme).

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2.